# After playing a Swap Your Hand card should the player draw in Saboteur 2?

Tags: saboteur-2

When *player A* plays a *Swap Your Hand* card he or she changes his or her cards with somebody else (*player B*). Then *player B* draws a card. Should *player A* draw a card too?

The general rules say that

> Play an action card... then draw 1 card.

, but in this case *player A* gets an extra card. On the other hand the rules of the *Swap Your Hand* card say

> Discard the action card, then the other player gets to draw 1 card!

Does it mean that *player A* should not draw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Player A should not draw.  The player the card was played *on* is the one who draws.

Another way to think about it:

Before the swap turn, Player A has X cards and Player B has Y cards.  Player A plays a swap on Player B.  Assuming the deck has cards in it, afterward Player A should have Y cards and Player B should have X cards.

Another way to think about it:

If both players have a full complement of 6 cards, and a swap is played, both players should end up with 6 cards when the dust settles.  Assuming there are cards left in the deck, of course.

Comment: It would be nice with some authoritative ruling on this. This interpretation *might* be the intention of the rules. But as I read the rules, they are completely logically compatible with both players drawing cards. The "Swap Your Hand" explanation just states that the other player gets to draw. It does not say that that player A does not draw. The earlier rules clearly state that players should draw a card at the end of their turn.